# Socket.IO client event handler not called?

Tags: socket.io

I'm an iOS developer who recently started using Socket.IO. During the life cycle of my iOS application, my server will be receiving messages from my app as the client, but for one particular case, the server will also need to receive a message from a web browser as the client. I'm testing a very basic browser UI, which includes a text field and a button and on the tap of that button, a numeric code (which was entered in the text field) needs to be sent to the server. This is what that looks like:

```
<form>
  Code:<br>
  <input type="text" id="code" name="code"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="validatebutton" value="Validate">
  <script src="/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("validatebutton").onclick = function() {
      var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
      socket.on('connect', function(clientSocket) {
        clientSocket.emit('validateCode', document.getElementById("code"));
      });
    };
  </script>
</form>
```

The connection works fine. When I run this code, the client successfully connects to the listening socket server. The only problem is that the event handler is not executed. I may be very off here, but what I went for is a client event handler, which is included in the Swift SDK:

```
self.socket.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: { (data:[Any], ack:SocketAckEmitter) in
    // Do something here
})
self.socket.connect()
```

I'm just assuming that the Javascript client has a client event handler (named `'connect'`) as well, which is received by the client at the moment of connecting to a server. Like I said, I may be way off here. I'm just following the Socket.IO documentation posted on their website, which tells me to do it this way. If someone can tell me what I'm missing, or what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated. Sorry for all the noobishness, but I really don't know where else to turn, since the official documentation is very vague and the other question on Stack are a little too advanced for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't put the `emit` function inside the connect. Try emitting like below in your client

```
  <script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    document.getElementById("validatebutton").onclick = function() {
       socket.emit('validateCode', document.getElementById("code"));
    };
  </script>
```

Your click event was probably getting executed, but the emit was not due to it being wrapped in the `connect` function (which only gets executed when the socket connects to the server)

Also I would put the JavaScript in its own file, but for now, at least after the form (not inside it) will work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It did change the process a little, as I was initially going for a quick connection, where the client only emits the message and then immediately disconnects from the server again, which is why the socket connection was initially inside the `onclick` function. This works just as well, though, so it's all good. Moreover, as far as I could read anything about it, the Javascript client doesn't appear to have a `.connect` and `.disconnect` function, unlike the Swift client, so I probably wouldn't have been only to disconnect after emitting the message anyway.

Comment: One last (unrelated) question: how do I emit a message to multiple connected clients? I know how to emit a message to a particular client, but is it also possible to pass an array of clients to send a message to? Right now I'm trying (on the server-side): `io.to(sockets.join()).emit("myMessage", someData);` but this doesn't appear to be doing anything. Weird part is, I'm not getting an error either, so I have absolutely no idea whether this is wrong or right.

Comment: here is a node.js example. On the server side to emit to ALL clients you can do something as simple as `var io = require('socket.io')(http);` and then `io.emit("myIdentifier", myData);`. As for sending to only a subset of connected clients I am not sure off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: That's okay, I already got it. You just have to create Rooms if you want to emit to a specific group of clients. First you add the clients to that room with `clientSocket.join('myRoom');` and when you want to emit to every client that's been added to that room, you just go `io.to('myRoom').emit('myMessage', someData);`. Simple as that. Thanks again for all the help! Appreciate it.